# confusion matrix is showing single output

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm performing deep learning sentiment classification with positive and negative outputs using glove as word embeddings. After Training I'm trying to create the confusion matrix using test data. however it is giving only 1 number output. Below are the training and testing code.

Training Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dropout, Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

movie_reviews = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/automobile.csv")

movie_reviews.isnull().values.any()

movie_reviews.shape
movie_reviews.head()

movie_reviews["tweet"][3]

import seaborn as sns

sns.countplot(x='Overall_Sentiment', data=movie_reviews)

def preprocess_text(sen):
    # Removing html tags
    sentence = remove_tags(sen)

    # Remove punctuations and numbers
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)

    # Single character removal
    sentence = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sentence)

    # Removing multiple spaces
    sentence = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sentence)

    return sentence

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

X = []
sentences = list(movie_reviews['tweet'])
for sen in sentences:
    X.append(preprocess_text(sen))

y = movie_reviews['Overall_Sentiment']

y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x=="positive" else 0, y)))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

# Adding 1 because of reserved 0 index
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

maxlen = 100

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)

from numpy import array
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import zeros

embeddings_dictionary = dict()
glove_file = open('/content/drive/My Drive/glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding="utf8")

for line in glove_file:
    records = line.split()
    word = records[0]
    vector_dimensions = asarray(records[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_dictionary [word] = vector_dimensions
glove_file.close()


embedding_matrix = zeros((vocab_size, 100))
for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_dictionary.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector

model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen , trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

print(model.summary())


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=6, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Test Score:", score[0])
print("Test Accuracy:", score[1])

plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train','test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])

plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train','test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Testing Code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                       batch_size=128, verbose=2)


new_prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, np.argmax(new_prediction,axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
[[19924]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your `y_test` and `new_prediction` both only contain one class.
Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_mat

y_test = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
y_pred = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output:

```
[[5]]
```

**Solution:** As soon as `y_test` or `new_prediction` contain more than one class, the output looks more like a confusion matrix.

```
y_test = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
y_pred = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1])
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

output:

```
[[3 2]
 [1 4]]
```

Comment: hi thanks this resolved the problem. however my algorithm is showing [[10001     0]
 [ 9923     0]] output meaning only true positive and false positive.

Comment: If it helped, it would be nice if you would accept/upvote ;)

maybe try more epochs. 6 epochs is not much. Go for 100 at least and see if it helps

Comment: No epochs are note making any changes. Only the True positive and False positive are showing. other two are zeros